# How to keep a radio button checked after closing the application - android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am new to coding in Android Studio and I just learned about Shared Prefrences.
My teacher gave me an assignment to make a Radio Button Group (RadioGroup), that when you check one of the buttons, close the app, open it again, the button will remain checked.

Just like you  would save an `EditText` answer with `SharedPrefrences`, I need  to save a `RadioButton` with `SharedPrefrences`.

As I said  I am new to this, so please keep the answer simple :)

--SOLVED-- Thank you all for answering! i found my solution thanks to your comments! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   // this will be key for the key value pair
   public static final String BUTTON_STATE = "Button_State";
   // this is name of shared preferences file, must be same whenever accessing
   // the key value pair.
   public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

   SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // helper method to open up the file.
      sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      // grab the last saved state here on each activity start
      Boolean lastButtonState = sharedpreferences.getBoolean(BUTTON_STATE, false)
      RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_button);
      // restore previous state
      rb.setChecked(lastButtonState);
      // set a listener
      rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            // call this to enable editing of the shared preferences file
            // in the event of a change
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            Boolean isChecked = rb.isChecked();
            // use this to add the new state
            editor.putBoolean(BUTTON_STATE, isChecked);
            // save
            editor.apply();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first, you want to set listener to the `RadioGroup` like so:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // save id into your SharedPreferences
        }
    });
```

And than you can restore it in onCreate() from shared preferences and call `radioGroup.check(id);`.
So the code will look something like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int checkedId = sharedPrefs.getInt("your key", 0);
radioGroup.check(checkedId);
```

Please note that this code is simplified. You need to add checks and so on

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radio_gropup);
    final SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("saved", 0);

    radioGroup.check(preferences.getInt("CheckedId", 0));

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("CheckedId", checkedId);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how** you are supposed to get the **onCheckChangeListener** on a radio group to get the selected radio button in it!

> NOTE!!! THERE SHOULD BE IDs GIVEN TO ALL INNER RADIO BUTTONS

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);

            //textViewChoice.setText("You Selected " + rb.getText());
           // here the rb.getText() will give you the text and you can send it to your
           //sharedPreference with a new key value like you did with the editText values
        }
    });
```

**And** when your app starts you can check in your onCreate() by the sharefPreference if the value is saved then get the RadioButton and set its property isSelected as true! I hope that is simple enough!